# Function passed to directive doesn't update variables from calling controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a authentication directive that looks like this:

```
function loginModal(jwtHelper, responseStringProvider, loadingScreen, $timeout, $http, $route) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            onLogin: '=method',
            control: '='
        },
        link: linkFunc,
        templateUrl: 'partials/loginModal.html',
        controller: loginCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'loginVm',
        bindToController: true
    };

    function linkFunc(scope, elm, attrs) {
        if (scope.loginVm.onLogin) {
            scope.loginVm.onLogin();
        }
        scope.loginVm.externalControl = scope.loginVm.control || {};
        scope.loginVm.externalControl.authenticate = scope.loginVm.authenticate;
    }
    function loginCtrl($scope) {
        //viewmodel
        var vm = this;

        //bound functions
        vm.authenticate = authenticate;


        function authenticate(functionToRunOnLogin) {
                functionToRunOnLogin(sessionStorage.token, sessionStorage.username).then(function (functionResponse) {
                        loadingScreen.hide();
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }, function (functionResponse) {
                        if (functionResponse.status === 401) {
                            loadingScreen.hide();
                            $('#invalidOperationDialog').modal({ backdrop: 'static' });
                        }
                        });
        }
```

There is a single instance of this directive in the index page. The controller for this directive is stored in a $scope variable

index.html:

`<login-modal control="vm.authenticationControl"></login-modal>`

indexController.js:

`vm.authenticationControl = {};`

`$scope.loginDirective = vm.authenticationControl;`

To run a function that needs authentication another controller accesses the directive's authenticate function from the $scope variable and passes the function that needs the authentication

settingsController.js

```
function openAuthDialog(value) {
            settingsVm.currentAction = value;
            $scope.loginDirective.authenticate(authorize);
        };


         function authorize(token, username) {

            switch (settingsVm.currentAction) {
                case settingsVm.globalSettingAction:
                    if (_isUpdated) {
                        return settingsVm.saveGlobalSettings(token, username);
                    }
                    break;
                case settingsVm.edsAddEditAction:
                    return settingsVm.edsAddEditConfirm(token, username);
                    break;
                case settingsVm.edsDeleteAction:
                    return settingsVm.edsDeleteConfirm(token, username);
                    break;
                case settingsVm.updateYellowPod:
                case settingsVm.updateBluePod:
                case settingsVm.updateDrillThrough:
                    return updateImagePath(token, username);
                    break;
            }

        }


         function saveGlobalSettings(token, username) {
            settingsVm.isSaving = true;
            var globalSettings = getCurrentGlobalSettings();

            return GlobalSettings.save(globalSettings, username, token)
                .then(function () {
                    //success
                    GlobalSettings.setGlobalSettingsChanges(globalSettings);
                    _savedGlobalSettings = globalSettings;
                    _isUpdated = false;

                    openDialogModal('Global Settings have been updated successfully.');
                },
                function () {
                    //error
                    openDialogModal( 'There was an error updating Global Settings at this time. Please try again later.');
                });
        }

         function openDialogModal( message) {
            settingsVm.modalMessage = message;
            $('#dialogModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static' });
        }
```

settings.html:

```
 <div id="dialogModal" class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false" style="z-index: 30000">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    Update Result
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4>
                        <span ng-bind-html="settingsVm.modalMessage"></span>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="globalSettingsVm.closeDialogModal()">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Most of the functions that are being passed to the directive simply need a token to make a call to the back end. The directive provides that token and runs the function and the back end updates the database. 
But there are a couple that need to make front end changes, which is where the problems arises.

After successfully saving the settings, the `settingsVm.saveSettings` function tries to set `settingsVm.modalMessage`, but there is no change to the page.
I have stepped through and can see the `settingsVm.modalMessage` get updated, so I know the function is running properly but cannot figure out why it's not reflected on the page. My suspicion is that the scope of the directive is not set up properly so when `settingsVm.modalMessage` gets updated it is not in the parent scope which means that instance of `settingsVm.modalMessage` is not bound to the html. My other thought is that I am not using `$scope.$apply` properly

I have tried many different scope setups for the directive but nothing works. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Can you add your code for `settingsController`? The js & HTML

Comment: @TristanHessell, I added the relevant parts of those two file, thanks!